# ggplot2: Overlapping elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data for low and high mean temperatures of each month of year. I put them in a bar plot, the lower temperatures over the higher temperatures, to see the difference. But I would like to have there only the difference, so what is overlapping (and blue on the plot) to be blank. Is there any way how to work with overlapping elements in ggplot?

```
dat <- data.frame(1:12, 1:12, 1:12)
colnames(dat) <- c("Th", "Tl")
dat$code <- c("Jan",    "Feb",  "Mar",  "Apr",  "May",  "Jun",  "Jul",  "Aug",  "Sep",  "Oct",  "Nov",  "Dec")
dat$code <- factor(dat$code, levels = dat$code)
dat$Th <- c(42, 44, 53, 64, 75, 83, 87, 84, 78, 67, 55, 45)
dat$Tl <- c(27, 28, 35, 44, 54, 63, 68, 66, 59, 48, 38, 29)
dat

p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = clim$code, y = Th)) +
      geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
      geom_bar(data = dat, aes(x = clim$code, y = Tl), fill = "blue", stat="identity")
p
```

[image: plot]

Comment: R has a built-in vector of month abbreviations `month.abb`, which you can use to save some typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approximate a bar graph with `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = code, xend = code, y = Th, yend = Tl)) + 
    geom_segment(size = 14, alpha = 0.7)
```

[image: segment plot]

The y-axis doesn't go to zero by default anymore, but if you want it to (it's probably unnecessary for temperatures), you can add `expand_limits(y = 0)`.

---

If you want to actually use `geom_bar`, you can if you adjust your data so you make both sets of bars in one call, and then set the fill of the lower ones in the stack to an RGB value with `00` as the extra alpha (opacity) value. It's a bit more complicated, though:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat[-3] %>%    # calling a column `NA` causes problems
    mutate(Th = Th - Tl) %>%    # adjust top of stacked highs
    gather(var, val, Th, Tl) %>%    # reshape to long form
    ggplot(aes(x = code, y = val, fill = var)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', show.legend = FALSE) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(Th = 'gray30', Tl = '#00000000'))    # set fills/opacity
```

[image: barplot]

Also, because everybody was using `geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"` so much, a new `geom_col` with `stat = "identity"` as the default was added (h/t @hrbrmstr!), so you could pop in `geom_col(show.legend = FALSE)` above if you like, provided your ggplot is up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you. I have an additive qustion: If I do on the lower temperature a `geom_line(aes(x=clim$code, y=clim$Tl, group = 1))` and I would like to make the segment end in the line, then how can I do it?

Comment: I'm not wholly sure I understand what you want, but you can flip the `y` and `yend` aesthetics (direction doesn't matter here) so you can do `ggplot(dat, aes(x = code, xend = code, y = Tl, yend = Th)) + 
    geom_segment(size = 14, alpha = 0.7) + geom_line(group = 1)`

Comment: `geom_linerange` is another option here: `ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = code, ymin = Tl, ymax=Th)) +
  geom_linerange(size=10, colour="blue")`.

Comment: @eipi10 That's actually better; honestly, I can't remember which geoms take which aesthetics without checking the docs. Maybe I'll make a table...

Comment: @Alistaire That is not exactly what I ment. This is just about the points, no matter if it is a line or a bar. I would like to cut the lower parts of blokcs over their entire width accoarding to the line trajectory. (Just theoreticaly, I know that it is not much useful for this exact case)

Comment: Do you mean `geom_ribbon`? `ggplot(dat, aes(x = code, ymin = Tl, ymax = Th)) + geom_ribbon(group = 1)`

Comment: Well, not exactly, although the `geom_ribbon` is quite useful, thank you for this tip! 
I will make of it another question with some more data, because it is probably a little bit different problem.